# How do I migrate a VMWare Fusion virtual machine to Azure?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-fusion, azure

I have (had) an instance of VMWare Fusion installed on my MacBook Air but the licensing has expired and I'd prefer not to renew if I can host these vm's on Azure. They take up a lot of space, I pay for Azure, and I don't want to pay for VMWare Fusion if I don't have to.

Is there a way I can migrate these VM's to Azure?

Comment: VMWare Fusion licenses are perpetual they don't expire.

Comment: [Googled it for ya](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/07/14/step-by-step-migrating-from-vmware-to-microsoft-azure/)

Comment: I realize you will need a tool to convert form vmwares format to azure but software recommendations are not on topic so I can't do that. But the process after that is identical

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft describes those steps in detail - no additional SW tools needed:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/07/14/step-by-step-migrating-from-vmware-to-microsoft-azure/

In short you need to :

1. Convert VMware VM into a Hyper-V VM
2. Run your newly converted VMs in Hyper-V and update the drivers
3. Upload your new VM to Windows Azure and get it started